# How many vertices/edges/faces at most for a convex polyhedron that tiles space?

Tags: combinatorial-geometry, packing-and-covering, polyhedra, convex-polytopes

I wonder if this problem has already been examined before:

Consider a convex polyhedron that tiles $\mathbb R^3$. What is the maximum of vertices/edges/faces that such a polyhedron can have?

Intuitively, it seems that the truncated octahedron is best possible for edges (36) as well as for vertices (24)
Its packing is also known as ["bitruncated cubic honeycomb"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitruncated_cubic_honeycomb).

For faces, we can do better than 14, as there is a polyhedron with 16 faces that can be obtained as follows: Take a truncated tetrahedron and add on each triangular face a small pyramid that is a quarter of a tetrahedron. The tessellation of it is known as the [quarter cubic honeycomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarter_cubic_honeycomb), with each small tetrahedron "distributed" among its four neighbors.

**Questions:
Are these best possible?
What about the corresponding problem in higher dimensions?**

In $\mathbb R^4$, it looks like the polytope yielded by the equivalent of the "Quarter cubic honeycomb" tiles it. This one, based on the [truncated 5-cell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_5-cell) has 25 cells, 60 faces, 60 edges, and 25 vertices, and so for cells and vertices, it does again (slightly) better than the 24-cell with its 96 faces, 96 edges, and 24 vertices.

Answer (score 11):

In $\mathbb{R}^3$ this is a famous problem.See this [nice reference.](http://upcommons.upc.edu/revistes/bitstream/2099/944/1/st8-04-a1.pdf) (Danzer, Grunbaum, Shepard -- Does every type of polyhedron tile three-space). The best example at the time of the writing had 38 faces (an example of Engel).  For a lattice (periodic) tiling, the problem was solved (I think) by Delone (AKA Delaunay).

Comment: Thank you very much. So it seems quite hopeless to look for something better in $\mathbb R^4$ in spite of knowing that there are probably solutions with at least 50 cells...

Comment: Nothing is hopeless, but serious thought is called for...


Answer (score 10):

To supplement Igor's citation of Engel's polyhedron, here it is:

     
[image: Engel Polyhedron]

The figure above is from the paper by
Branko Grünbaum and G. C. Shephard,
"Tilings with congruent tiles",
[*Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. (N.S.)*, Volume 3, Number 3 (1980), 951-973](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-3/issue-3/Tilings-with-congruent-tiles/bams/1183547682.full)
and is copied from Peter Engel's paper "Über Wirkungsbereichsteilungen von kubischer Symmetrie", [*Zeitschrift für Kristallographie*, volume 154 (1981), number 3–4, 199–215](https://dx.doi.org/10.1524/zkri.1981.154.3-4.199).
It is certainly remarkable that this polyhedron tiles space!

---

**Addendum** (*10Oct13*):
Now that Günter brought this back to the front page with
the precise citation (thanks!), I'll add
that a student Tiffany Liu and I 3D-printed copies of the
18-sided plesiohedra found by Löckenhoff and Hellner that tile space
so we could see how they fit together. Here they are inside the 3D printer: 

         
[image]

Comment: Thank you. Nice article! I see on p.961 that others have had the same idea as me a century before...

Comment: it's only a pity that they didn't ask their computer to provide an illustration how to tile space with it. Hopefully their program is trustworthy!